# window.open(); window.focus() not working on MAC firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen answers around to the question about opening a new tab "in the background" as in keeping the focus on the current window.

The answer was just to self.focus() or window.focus() after calling window.open() for the new tab.  This works all around EXCEPT for Macintosh Firefox.  Does anyone know why this is? and if there is a way to get it working here as well?

Thank you.